# Looking for a way to auto-fetch or auto-synchronize all repositories used in workspace upon opening

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I'm looking, out of convienience, for a way to be notified automaticaly upon opening eclipse workspace with some source controled projects about changes that were made if any.

The way I visualize it is:
1) I open Eclipse selecting workspace A
2) During boot-up work in eclipse for workspace A, it would find all repositories which have projects imported to this workspace A
3) The fetching/synchronizing work will be launched.
4) Upon finishing synching/fetching one of the Repo's, it will visualize the state of the project by the up/down arrows that are typical for displaying how far is the current branch from the remote.

Is there any option/3rd party plugin that can achieve what I described above, or something as close to that as possible?

Currently, I have to manualy either fetch all projects under source control when I open Eclipse (with some particular workspace) or use Team->Synchronize workspace option. But:
a) It is not convienient if I have to do it every day, and with every workspace I open.
b) The projects that are in some of the workspaces are not all under source control, so I can't just select all projects and hit Team->Synchronize. I have to select only projects that are under version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Eclipse plugin that I know of which would:

- extends EGit
- provide the kind of global monitoring that you are after.

I have only seen it with [Tower 2](http://www.git-tower.com/) (but it is a Mac client)

The Windows/Mac git client [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) does have automatic fetch.
In any case, that would involve a third-party client, which is not convenient, but can be tried as a workaround.

Comment: I always appritiate someone taking their time to help, even if it's not the answer I was hoping for. After investigating it a bit at that time I couldn't find anything close to what I was looking for, so I wanted to inquire others. Seems there is simply not a tool like that at this point, which still is some kind of an answer to my question. Better have bad answer, than to live in unknown land. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution is to set a script which updates each repo at system startup, or replace eclipse launcher with a script that does that then launches eclipse.

About the notification issue, you can use [git-multimail](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/hooks/multimail/README?id=HEAD) if you are using git or an alternative if you use other SCM software.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I'm not exactly looking for auto-fetching all my local repos, since that is not needed for me. Say I have 50 local repositories but only 1 of these changes. That would mean on every startup 49 are being fetched, coompletely unnecceseary.

Answer (score 0):

GitKraken is a standalone pretty good Git Tool and it also has "autofetch".

You can connect it to your repository, which you already synchronised with eclipse. You can set "Autofetch" up under Preferences and also you can choose an interval between 1 and 60 min.